# AngularJS array value contains HTML tags, doesn't display correctly when called

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array (in Angular), that looks like this

```
$scope.posts = [
    {
        "ID" : id(),
        "Title" : "A",
        "Company" : "Company A",
        "Location" : "San Francisco, CA",
        "Date" : "2016-06-20",
        "Description": "Description<br>Desciption part 2",
     }
];
```

The description is called with a `<p>{{post.description}}</p>` in a div with `ng-repeat = "post in posts"`.

The result however is that it shows up like this

`Description.<br>Description part 2`

Instead of

Description
Description part 2.

The same goes for inserting `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

Is there any way I can get the html structure in the array value to actually show up as html and not explicitly displayed like this?

Comment: My answer should fix the problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use something like `ng-bind-html="post.Description"` for it to be displayed as HTML.

Or you could possibly use `ngSanitize` to cleanse the HTML

Something like here - https://jsfiddle.net/datachand/szc550yb/4/

In controller, try using `$sce.trustAsHtml(post.Description)` if needed

Comment: Using this causes the console to log an error stating `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{post.Description}}] starting at [{post.Description}}].`

Comment: `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context`

Answer (score 1):

Use the ngBindHtml directive from angular to display html correctly:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Also, take into account that you will need to add ngSanitize to your module.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>{{post.Description}}</p>
```

capital Description